# Find the button but can't click it

Tags: autoit

The SDK I'm trying to run has first a preparing to install step and then shows the next button. So I'm waiting until I see the button.

When the next button shows up the ConsolWrite writes in the loop. But I'm not able to click the button. Also tried send("!n") and it doesn't work.

```
 #include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>

Global $hCtrl = 0, $Waiting = True

$wintitle = "SigCaptureWeb SDK - InstallShield Wizard"
ShellExecute("C:\SigCaptureWeb.exe")

; your GUI loop
While (1)
    If $Waiting And WinExists($wintitle) Then
        $hCtrl = ControlGetHandle($wintitle, "", "[CLASS:Button; TEXT:&Next >]")
        If $hCtrl Then
            ; we got the handle, so the button is there
            ; now do whatever you need to do
            ConsoleWrite("in the loop")
            ControlClick($wintitle,"", "[CLASS:Button; TEXT:&Next >]","{ENTER}")
            $Waiting = False
        EndIf
    EndIf

    $iMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $iMsg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            ExitLoop
    EndSwitch
WEnd
```

Comment: `ControlClick` controls the mouse, not the keyboard. Replace `"{ENTER}"` with `"primary"` or skip that parameter to use default `"left"`

Comment: @Stephan was a left over from something I tried. I skipped it before and didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to run the script as admin to interact with the installer that runs as admin.

Testing the AutoIt installer with `ShellExecute` allows the script to detect the window though clicking the button is not working as the script is running as not admin. This could be considered a security feature of the OS to protect the admin process.

This may work for you. I am not sure why you have gui code etc. so I am leaving that out.

```
; This is a compile directive to make the compiled script run as admin.
#pragma compile(ExecLevel, requireAdministrator)

; This directive is for uncompiled script to run as admin.
#RequireAdmin

$wintitle = "SigCaptureWeb SDK - InstallShield Wizard"
Run("C:\SigCaptureWeb.exe")

WinWait($wintitle)

; Wait for Next button to become visible.
While Not ControlCommand($wintitle, "", "&Next >", "IsVisible", "")
    Sleep(250)
WEnd

ControlClick($wintitle, "", "&Next >")
```

Being an InstallShield installer, it may have arguments that you could pass to the executable to initiate a silent install which may make it easier. You could look into that.

Comment: Don't think the admin rights are the problem. Tried yours but it doesn't work. Reason I use the gui is becasuse the window pops up but without the button. It has a progress bar and then shows the button. So I thought I had to wait and check until the button was available and then click it. But It doesn't either :)

Comment: If a delay is needed then `controlcommand` can get the state of a control. I do not know the behavior of this install except for what you inform so forgive if I do not have correct code initially. `guigetmsg` etc. has no part in your code so I am confused why it is there. `send` and `control*` function need to be admin to act with an admin process, give it a chance before doubting. Get it working and then try disabling admin directives and check if still working. if th install only adds files to your profile folder then perhaps admin is not needed. I do not know if the installer prompts admin.